# Frobenius norm of matrix $A^{T}A$ is $trace(A^{T}A)$? Where all of the values in the matrix $A$ are real

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

We know that frobenius norm of a matrix $A$ is given by $\|A\|_{F}=\sqrt{trace(A^{T}A)}$. Can we write frobenius norm of matrix $A^{T}A$ to be $\|A^{T}A\|_{F}=trace(A^{T}A)$, that is I am effectively getting rid of the square root symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=\left( \begin{array}{cc} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$.

$\left\| A^TA \right\|_F=\sqrt{trace(A^TAA^TA)}=\sqrt{17}$

However, $trace(A^TA)=5$.

Hence the equality doesn't hold.